# Move to regional office

Tags: new-job

I'm mid career (40M). After a decade in my current role, I have come to a decision point.

Either:

1. take a promotion to a regional office in a GREAT city, where I will be responsible for half the office, and be able to afford a house with a view of the sea;

or

2. grind it out a few more years at HQ waiting for a promotion. This requires that my current manager retires, which will be about two to three years.

It seems obvious, right? But the regional office is quite minor, whereas at HQ I work directly with the big boss, which gets me lots of exposure. Basically I'll be going from being a small fish in a big pond, to being the big fish in a beautiful, but small pond. Any thoughts?

Comment: `It seems obvious, right?` Clearly not, otherwise we would not be seeing this question. :)

Comment: Too many inknown factors: partner, kids, schools, extended family....

Comment: -It is a gamble. Situation can change in moment`s notice, see current pandemic thing. Your decision must be yours alone, you need to weight stability potential of both positions alongside of your carrier prospects of staying in the current role and promotion to higher responsibility but lower exposure

Comment: What is obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

I, for one, personally do not make choices based on some future event that might happen. Accept the current opportunity, make the most of it, and when time comes, look for a better one.

Assuming the only deciding factor here is career path / growth,

- I'd say, accept the offer for the Regional office, move other there, show your skills - that you can be useful while being away from HQ (some people can only work in a niche, not a good sign for growth). In parallel, start grooming people who can replace you in that role, if (and when) you chose to move out from that role.
- Then, once your manager at HQ retires, put up your application for the post.

Comment: Also, ten years a long time already. If getting a promotion is important to him, he may just want to accept the regional office job, and then apply to other companies.